# how do I change the state of icon only on the one that is playing audio?

Tags: jquery

hello guys I have done the following code but when i play a sound it seem that is changing the icon for the all divs not only the one that is playing. Any idea how can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/1rdoxe84/1/

JS

```
$('.playButton').hover(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("m-icon--hovered");    
}, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("m-icon--hovered");
});

var playing = false;
var sound;
var icon = $('.playButton');
$('.audio').on('click', function() {
    if(playing === false){
        playing = true; 
        sound = $(this).children()[1];
        sound.play();
        icon.attr('src','https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-tab-bar/25/Pause-512.png');
        setTimeout(function(){
        playing = false;
            sound.pause();
            sound.currentTime = 0;
            icon.attr('src','http://www.wayfm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/playButton-150x150.png');
        },3000);
    } else {
        playing = false;
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;
        icon.attr('src','https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-tab-bar/25/Pause-512.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
...
$('.audio').on('click', function() {
    var icon = $(this).find('.playButton');
    ...
```